# How to localize or change text for the Identity Management menu items

Tags: localization, abp

I'm trying to change the text for the "Identity management" menu item which is added up in the ABP framework somewhere.  Is it possible find the localization key somewhere to add it to my en.json file or do I have to plunk through the `context.Menu.GetAdministration()` menu items in my MenuContributor and hack it there?  I've tried a bunch of different variations in the en.json file to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Abp Localization Docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization#extending-existing-resource)

1. Extend an existing resource JSON file

   - zh-Hans

   ```json
   {
     "culture": "zh-Hans",
     "texts": {    
       "Menu:IdentityManagement": "身份管理"    
     }
   }
   ```

   - en

   ```json
   {
     "culture": "en",
     "texts": {
       "Menu:IdentityManagement": "Identity"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Extending IdentityResource

   ```cs
   options.Resources
      .Get<IdentityResource>()
      .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/LocalizeModuleTest");
   ```
3. Effect is as follows

   [image][image]