# Abp Framework- Finding the translation Json for modules

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, abp

i have a an abp framework using blazor server app.
Im trying to modify the text for the Administration module and the blazor UI.
blazor UI being for example the "Sign Out" button to "Sign-Out", where does this text exsist? how to modify it? I cant see it in the project at all.
Same for the administration module.
this doesnt exsist in my code :
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.UI/Localization/Resources/AbpUi/en.json

Answer (score 0):

You can look here https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Application.Contracts/Volo/Abp/Account/Localization/Resources/en.json#L48

There is a similar situation here. [How to localize or change text for the Identity Management menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450871/how-to-localize-or-change-text-for-the-identity-management-menu-items?rq=2)